# Fatal error: diff(): Unknown property (w)

Tags: php, таймер

После переезда с одного сервера на другой появилась такая ошибка, никак не могу понять в чем проблема. Помогите пожалуйста!

> Fatal error: diff(): Unknown property (w) in /var/www/arashvg/data/www/all-payeer.ru/bonus.php on line 199

Вот код

```
    function diff(DateTime $datetime2, DateTime $datetime1 = null)
{
    if (!isset($datetime1)) {
        $datetime1 = new DateTime('now');
    }

    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2, false);
    $days = $interval->days;

    // calculate seconds
    $interval->s = $datetime2->getTimestamp() - $datetime1->getTimestamp();
    $interval->i = floor($interval->s / 60);
    $interval->h = floor($interval->s / (60 * 60));
    $interval->d = $days;
    $interval->w = floor($days / 7); //На этой строке выдает ошибку 
    $interval->m = floor($days / $datetime1->format('t'));

    return $interval;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В документации http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php нет указания на недели, возможно, недели были в более ранеей версии PHP, потом были убраны. Можно сделать 2 вещи в этом случае:

1. Узнать версию PHP на старом сервере, и попробовать поставить ее на новом.
2. Убрать или заменить устаревший код.

Кроме того вы задаете недели вместе с днями, что неправильно с точки зрения PHP: http://php.net/manual/ru/dateinterval.construct.php

> W -   недели. Преобразуется в дни, поэтому не может быть использован
>   совместно с D.

Ну и самый последний вопрос, я не понимаю, зачем этот код, если вы уже посчитали интервал здесь?

```
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2, false);
```

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужно получить интервал в секундах.

Comment: Тогда почему бы просто не посчитать разницу в секундах? `$datetime1->getTimestamp() - $datetime2->getTimestamp()`

Comment: все разобрался, спасибо! ))